# OpenLayers 3 toggle feature visibility

Tags: openlayers, jquery

This seemed simple on the face of it, but I am unable to figure out how to toggle the visibility of a marker feature using the Version 3 API of OpenLayers.

In my situation, I am adding features to a vector layer. Each feature is a marker icon denoting a place of interest. When I click on a checkbox somewhere else on the page, I'd like for the feature to appear of disappear (as the case may be). I am using JQuery in conjunction with OL3, but I don't care whether the solution is jquery or vanilla javascript.

Code snippets:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    projection: "EPSG:4326"
});
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: fieldIconStyle
});



var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [osm, digitalglobe, vectorLayer],//osm and digitalglobe exist in unquoted code
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
            collapsible: false
        })
    }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    })
});

function checkedchanged(item)//item is the checkbox that was clicked
{
    //this function does get called successfully.
    //alert($(item).prop('checked'));
    var selected = $(item).prop('checked');
    var id = $(item).val();

    vectorSource.forEachFeature(function (item) {

        var props = item.getProperties();
        if (props.FieldId = id) {
            item.setStyle({visible: selected});//I have tried many different things here, all to no avail
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Same here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/33694686/4640499

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been struggling with the same issue, but I seem to have come across a solution that works pretty well.

In the Docs there is no `visibility` style option for vector features. But you can set the `opacity` of an `ol.style.Icon` or the alpha of the `fill` and `stroke` for an `ol.style.Circle` and `ol.style.RegularShape`

How I got it to work was to set a style functions for my visible and invisible states. Here are a few options for points

```
//visible style
var visibleStyleIcon = {
     'Point': [new ol.style.Style({
         image: new ol.style.Icon({
             src : 'your_icon.png',
             opacity : 1
         })
     })]
 };

// invisible Style Icon Opacity
var invisibleStyleIcon = {
    'Point': [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            src : 'your_icon.png', //still need something even if it's invisible
            opacity : 0
        })
    })]
};

// invisible Style Vector Alpha
var hiddenStyle = {
    'Point': [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 5,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            })
        })
    })]
};

// invisible Style Shape No Points
var hiddenStyleRegularShape = {
    'Point': [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.RegularShape({}) //a shape with no points is invisible
    })]
}
```

Then for the feature you want to hide/unhide just set the style for that feature

```
if (feature_should_be_visible){
    feature.setStyle(visibleStyleIcon[feature.getGeometry().getType()]);
} else {
    feature.setStyle(invisibleStyleIcon[feature.getGeometry().getType()]);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that there was an official way of doing this, but I guess you can't always get what you want. I'll just have to add a custom IsVisible flag to each feature to track its visibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found a simpler method, **It only works if you have only one feature with the same image setted**:

```
feature.getStyle().getImage().setOpacity(0) // Invisible
feature.getStyle().getImage().setOpacity(1) // Visible
// After doing this, you need to "refresh" the map. In Open Layers 3 it's
vectorLayer.changed()
```

If 2 or more features share the same Image Object they will dissapear at the same time.

I hope it helps, sorry about my English, it's not my native language.